# Custom product name in cart from backend

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom, backend, name

Is there a way to modify the name of a product when creating an order from backend? For example we have a product called "special order" and would like to rename with the specific name of the product when creating the order from backend. This product would have a different name and custom price everytime it is used.

Comment: I figured out how to solve my problem: added a custom option with field text to write the product description.